# Opening URL in new window with paramters

Tags: javascript, reporting-services

I have the following code in the URL of an SSRS report to open a report 'GL TTM.rdl' in a new window. 
The label parameter just takes in a string value 'month'

However, when I click on the link, nothing happens. Please help me figure out What is wrong in this code?

Also, what changes should I make to get this new page to export to Excel ?

```
    ="javascript:void window.open(" &"'"& Globals!ReportServerUrl &"/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?"
  &Globals!ReportFolder 
  & "/GL+TTM
  &cono="& Fields!cpnyid.Value &"
 &PLRow="&Fields!PLrow.Value &"
 &fiscyr="&Fields!fiscyr.Value &"
&MonthName="&Fields!MonthName.Value &"
&label="'month'"
&Category="&Fields!Category.Value &"
 ','_blank')"
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it. I removed all quotes from the parameter value for 'label' and also removed the + from the report name

```
="javascript:void window.open(" &"'"& Globals!ReportServerUrl 
  &"/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?"
  &Globals!ReportFolder 
   & "/GL TTM
  &cono="& Fields!cpnyid.Value &"
  &PLRow="&Fields!PLrow.Value &"
  &fiscyr="&Fields!fiscyr.Value &"
  &MonthName="&Fields!MonthName.Value &"
 &label= month
  &Category="&Fields!Category.Value &"
   ','_blank')"
```